# How to skip remaining task in Ansible and create certain conditions

Tags: ansible

I would like to create the following condition below. Any ideas how to proceed? I've tried When Condition, set_facts, looping [], but I'm not succeding it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Example of vars that has been generated:

```
version_detected: "9.0.0.7"

version_available:   "9.1.0.3"
                     "9.0.0.7",
                     "8.0.0.13"
```

**Create a condition where**

```
If "version_detected" is inside "version_available", then skip all remaining tasks and end playbook with a debug message.

If "version_detected" is not inside "version_available", then continue playbook for the next task.
```

**Next Task:**

```
If "version_detected" contains "8.0", then download file www.site.com/fixpack80.gz to path

If "version_detected" contains "9.0", then download file www.site.com/fixpack90.gz to path

If "version_detected" contains "9.1", then download file www.site.com/fixpack91.gz to path
```

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable with only `when` conditions, assuming that `version_available` is a list.

For example:

```
  vars:
    version_detected: "9.0.0.7"
    version_available: ["9.1.0.3", "9.0.0.7", "8.0.0.13"]

  tasks:
    - fail:
        msg: Unsupported version
      when: version_detected not in version_available

    - debug:
        msg: Do some task for version 8.0.x.x
      when: '"8.0" in version_detected'

    - debug:
        msg: Do some task for version 9.0.x.x
      when: '"9.0" in version_detected'
```